# Android .aab not able to generate

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-databinding

I am using dynamic feature delivery with data binding. I used base module and feature using data binding. I am trying to generate .aab but I am not able to generate .aab file. I showing below error.

Program type already present: android.databinding.layouts.DataBindingInfo